# I cannot remove spaces from a string passed as props in React

Tags: string, split, react-props

The component receives a props which corresponds to a string: "1 586 826 492 016".
When I try to delete the spaces it doesn't work.
However if I test with a simple variable it works.

```
import React from 'react'

const NotifUpdated = ({ updated }) => {

    const num = "12 000 000"

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {
                    updated ? updated.split(' ').join('') : null
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                {
                    num ? num.split(' ').join('') : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotifUpdated
```

**updated** returns 1 586 826 492 016 while **num** returns 12000000

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this props was set with .toLocalString() in another component